# Locked out of GitHub and can't get support

Tags: authentication, github, 12factor

All of a sudden GitHub's 2FA stopped working and I'm now locked out. The account was set to use pass keys. The PKs are managed by my password manager (Dashlane) but GitHub would no longer accept them. I tried switching to the TOTP (Microsoft Authenticator), which is set up for GitHub, but the generated codes are also not accepted. Double checked iPhone's time setting (as per recommendation) and it's already set to Automatic.

Now, I do have a set of recovery codes but there seems to be no way to submit them. The support docs instructs me to pick the recovery code option in the "Having problems" box, under the failed login attempt, but that box contains a single option: "Reconfigure 2FA on this account", which is what makes it possible to switch between passcoded or TOTP, and nothing else.

I then tried using the AI assistant, which guides me through various options, all of which I have already tested. At the end of the "conversation" it asks me if I have recovery keys. I answer "yes". The assistant then simply congratulates me, as I'm in the luck, apparently, and then wishes me a great day. No instructions for how to actually use the recovery codes.

Desperate, I finally googled the link to GitHub community, so I could ask other users. Turns out that requires I login with 2FA!

Either I'm mad, or the GitHub auth and recovery mechanism is a textbook example for how not to design systems.

I'm out of ideas for now, and would greatly appreciate any hints on how to move on.

Comment: I can only sign in Github with Github moblie app. The 2FA or passkey is not working for me.